# CSimpleString::SetLength() Exception in Visual C++ Windows Service

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I am trying to find the root cause of an `COleException` being thrown by my service in production environment. I have checked the crash dump file, and the exception is thrown when trying to construct a string.

COleException is thrown inside `void SetLength(_In_ int nLength)`:

```
void SetLength(_In_ int nLength)
{
    ATLASSERT( nLength >= 0 );
    ATLASSERT( nLength <= GetData()->nAllocLength );

    if( nLength < 0 || nLength > GetData()->nAllocLength)
        AtlThrow(E_INVALIDARG); // EXCEPTION THROWN HERE BECAUSE GetData()->nAllocLength IS 0 WHILE nLength IS 38

    GetData()->nDataLength = nLength;
    m_pszData[nLength] = 0;
}
```

Since this is deep inside Microsoft's code (`atlsimpstr.h`) I'm not certain what is happening. Just wondering if anyone has experienced `CString` behaving like this?

Call stack:

- `ATL::CSimpleString::SetLength()`
- `ATL::CSimpleString::ReleaseBufferSelLength()`
- `ATL::CString::FormatV()`
- `ATL::CString::Format()`
- `ActiveSocket->ErrorText.Format("Socket %d failed during read?. Error %s", ActiveSocket->Handle, (LPCSTR)Socket::SockErrorAsPrintable(ActiveSocket->Handle));`

`ActiveSocket->ErrorText` is of type `CString`.

I am using Windows SDK 10.0, v142 Platform Toolset and C++ Language Standard is set to ISO C++14 Standard.

Comment: This is more an internal error because ATL (and probably MSVC runtime) has computed the length itself. Can you reproduce the problem with a small example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if you can you should report to Microsoft

Comment: I suppose that you call SetLength with a value larger than the requested/allocated buffer. Get a full memory dump, check the callstack.

Comment: Show us the format and what you want to output.

Comment: @SimonMourier Unfortunately I cannot even reproduce this error on my production machine. All I can see is, it happens some time after DataDog Agent service is restarted

Comment: @xMRi Added to call stack.

Comment: @xMRi I'm not calling `SetLength()` myself. I am asking `CString` to format itself.

Comment: Are you running in multithreaded environment (ie: where the string is used by multiple threads)? That could cause that type of error.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes there are 60+ threads running in my process, and I must add I have inherited this code-base. From what I have seen in the code so far, `ActiveSocket` is not shared between different threads. It is _supposed to_ be assigned to one thread to own and manage.

Comment: If this CString is a member variable or possible accessed by multiple threads, you could try to add some lock when accessing it (with ATL there's RAII classes like CComCriticalSection)

Comment: @SimonMourier Unfortunately this code is run in a tight loop and we cannot afford the cost of synchronizing access. If nobody has faced this issue before, it might indeed be a race condition which means I have to go dig deeper into the code and make sure sockets are not shared between threads.

Comment: What does `SockErrorAsPrintable` look like? Does it, by any chance, return a pointer to a static buffer that could be overwritten by another call while in use?

Comment: User a temporal CString variable to Format. Than Assign the value.
Because of the reference counting you might get arround the synch problems.
CString str; str.Format(...);  ActiveSocket->ErrorText = str;